# Dynamic help function in discord.js not showing all commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a discord bot using Node.js and Discord.js. I am having a problem with my help command which should show all of the commands by looking at the '.js' files in the commands directory. However, it is only showing a small number of them ignoring the rest.

My file system is something like this:

```
./commands/
     fun/
        love.js
        rps.js
        meme.js
     info/
        help.js
        instagram.js
        invite.js
        ping.js
        whois.js
     moderation/
        clear.js
        kick.js
        report.js
        say.js
```

my help file also looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pagination = require('discord.js-pagination');
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client(); 
module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    aliases: ["h"],
    category: "info",
    description: "Returns all commands, or one specific command info",
    usage: "[command | alias]",
    run = async function(client, message, args[0]) {
    var wait = ms => new Promise((r, j)=>setTimeout(r, ms))
    var fff;
    var hmu = {};
    fs.readdir("./src/commands/", (err2, fff) => {
        for (i = 0; i < fff.length; i++) {
            hmu[i] = new discord.MessageEmbed();
            hmu[i].setTitle(fff[i]);
            hmu[i].setColor(config.embedColor);
            const iii = i;
            fs.readdir(`./src/commands/${fff[i]}/`, (err1, files1) => {
                files1.forEach((f2, i2) => {
                    const cmd = f2.replace('.js', '');
                  hmu[iii].addField(cmd, "testing");
                });
            });
        }  
    });
    await wait(50);
    var helppage = [];
    var f = 0;
    for (let step = 0; f == 0; step++) {
        if(hmu[helppage.length]) {
        helppage[helppage.length] = hmu[helppage.length];
        console.log("+1")
        } else {
            f = 1;
        }
    }
    await wait(50);
    const emojis = ["◀", "▶"];
    
    pagination(message, helppage, emojis)


 }
}
```

The commands that show are like the picture below:
[image: How it looks in output]
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you specify which commands it's showing? Also, your code has a major syntax error: `run = async function(client, message, args[0]) {`

Comment: Yes i will update the question in a second

Comment: and thank you for that notice i will try it out

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: That wasn't a fix to your problem, that was just something to point out.

Comment: Thank you for that, anyways. I always like to find out any points that can be improved.